# Unable to connect to wifi on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, wifi

I installed Linux Mint and am trying to connect to wifi, but this does not work.
On the system tray it shows the “connecting” icon for a while, then the “not connected” icon.

How can I investigate what's going wrong and make the wifi work?
Model is Intel(R) WiFi Link 1000BGN on a Dell Inspiron 14r laptop.

`dmesg` says:

```
wlan0: authenticate with 20:4e:7f:13:e1:58 (try 1)
[  152.358450] wlan0: authenticated
[  152.371768] wlan0: associate with 20:4e:7f:13:e1:58 (try 1)
[  152.377936] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 20:4e:7f:13:e1:58 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[  152.377939] wlan0: associated
[  152.385284] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[  153.041670] wlan0: deauthenticating from 20:4e:7f:13:e1:58 by local choice (reason=3)
```

Comment: Please give more data: What model is your wireless adapter? Does any error messages appear in `dmesg`?

Comment: i am new in linux. how to get dmg?model is interl(R) wifi link 1000BGN. laptop-dell inspiron 14r i3

Comment: type `dmesg` in a terminal and see if any wireless-related messages appear, then edit your question to add those.

Comment: Does the network have encryption on? Can you try your wireless with an open network?

Comment: how to check whether encryption is on.I have put password on my wifi.other laptop also i installed linux mint. it is working fine on it.but on this laptop wfi not working :(

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem several times. Do the following. I'm sure it will fix it.

```
$ rfkill unblock all
$ rfkill list all
```